# How to Deserialize complex JSON object having multiple roots using c#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, list, dictionary

I am reading Json response data from file (`oneProject.JSON` ), but getting `null` value in deseriliazation. Please help me to deserialise a complex JSON response having multiple objects:

JSON RESPONSE Data from File. FIle Name:oneProject.JSON

```
{
  "modelID": 199,
  "dataList": {
    "Inc__revenue": {
      "name": "Inc__revenue",
      "title": "Inc. Revenue",
      "description": "",
      "indexes": [
        "All_years",
        "All_countries"
      ],
      "data": [
        {
          "All_years": "2019",
          "All_countries": "UNITED STATES",
          "value": 0
        },
        {
          "All_years": "2020",
          "All_countries": "UNITED STATES",
          "value": 0
        },
        {
          "All_years": "2021",
          "All_countries": "UNITED STATES",
          "value": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**C# Code:Program.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Trail08
{
    class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var responseBody1 = File.ReadAllText("D:\\EnrichInput\\OneProject.JSON");
            var oneProj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<oneProjRoot>(responseBody1);
            Console.WriteLine(oneProj);
            Console.ReadLine();
            foreach (var item1 in oneProj.dataList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t :\t{1}",item1.All_years, item1.Value);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**ProjectDetails.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace Trail08
{
    public class oneProjRoot
    {
        public int modelID { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, dataListCls> dataList { get; set; }
        public class dataListCls
        {
            public int All_years { get; set; }
            public string All_countries { get; set; }
            public int value { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update the question with json file and the output of `Console.WriteLine("{0}\t :\t{1}",item1.All_years, item1.Value);`

Comment: Updated Json Response file content.. Please find the same.. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You class structure not matching with JSON. Use some online JSON/c# object generators, rather than creating them manually. Saves time. here is one https://app.quicktype.io/?l=csharp to consider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create objects properly to deserialise your json. Your object classes will look like below. You can use online tools like https://www.site24x7.com/tools/json-to-csharp.html to get a quick sample for json-to-objects.

```
public class Data {
 public string All_years { get; set; }
 public string All_countries { get; set; }
 public int value { get; set; }

}
public class Inc__revenue {
 public string name { get; set; }
 public string title { get; set; }
 public string description { get; set; }
 public IList<string> indexes { get; set; }
 public IList<Data> data { get; set; }

}
public class DataList {
public Inc__revenue Inc__revenue { get; set; } 

}
public class Application {
 public int modelID { get; set; }
public DataList dataList { get; set; } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model does not match with the JSON. Try to use the following (generated using [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io?share=XDjQ6hM2Iqu9aZV0C4Na)):

```cs
public partial class ProjectDetails
    {
        [JsonProperty("modelID")]
        public long ModelId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("dataList")]
        public DataList DataList { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class DataList
    {
        [JsonProperty("Inc__revenue")]
        public IncRevenue IncRevenue { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class IncRevenue
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("indexes")]
        public string[] Indexes { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public Datum[] Data { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Datum
    {
        [JsonProperty("All_years")]
        public string AllYears { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("All_countries")]
        public string AllCountries { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("value")]
        public long Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Sotiris,

Thanks a lot for your quick response. Its working.